# responseHeader.getSetCookie is not a function (Nextjs Route Handlers)

Tags: next.js

structure:

```
- src
  - app
    - api
      route.ts
    page.tsx
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "13.5.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18"
}
```

in route.ts:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function GET(request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json({ sdd: 'sd' });
}
```

result when get route `localhost:3000/api`:

```
TypeError: responseHeaders.getSetCookie is not a function
at new ResponseCookies (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/cookies/index.js:213:47)
at new NextResponse (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response.js:40:22)
```

I tried to simulate the error, but it happens normally:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-jtz1uc?file=app%2Fapi%2Froute.ts

Comment: Just started getting this error on 13.4.4 - upgrading to 13.5.1 or 13.5.5 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: There are some questions related to this problem in the Next.js repository: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56949

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve the problem by changing the version of the next:
13.5.5 to 13.5.1

Comment: I updated to Next 14.0.4 and worked

Answer (score 2):

It's a recent issue. I just ran on this myself, it helps to do one of the following:

- upgrade to NodeJs version 13.5.6
- downgrade to Next version 13.5.4
- switch to NodeJs version 18.6.

Related [github issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56949).

Answer (score 1):

They actually just [fixed this yesterday in `Next 13.5.6`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/56947#issuecomment-1769572453)! Upgrading to the latest version of Next worked for me.